# Java help for restart program

Tags: java, restart

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class Mal { 

    public static void main (String []args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome") ;
        Scanner myinput=new Scanner (System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Make your choice. \n 1.Check a card number \n 2.Quit.");
        int choise=myinput.nextInt();
        switch(choise) {
            case 1:System.out.println("Enter your credit card number: ");
            break;
            case 2:System.out.println("Are you sure?") ;
            String answer=myinput.next();

            if(answer.equals("yes")){
                System.out.println("Byee :)") ;
                System.exit(0);
            }
            break;
            default: System.out.println("Idiot!") ;
            break;
        }
    }       
}
```

i want a program which starts again if user types something different than "yes"

Comment: Is this homework? If so it would be polite to mention it.

Comment: I like your program in that you call your users an idiot. We need more of that kind of honesty!

Comment: @glowcoder - OP may want to reconsider calling the user an idiot.  Maybe the user was attempting to tell the program how to spell 'choice' before leaving.

Comment: @glowcoder: heroic observation... especially given that my users are a bunch of hypersensitive and paranoid analyst types.  From here on out I'm encoding more user abuse in my tools.

Comment: @amccormack It's probably an artifact of OP's non-English background (an assumption based on the OP's name.) In addition, many words that Americans would spell with a C, the British spell with an S (Defen**c**e vs Defen**s**e) so, as far as misspellings go, it could be significantly worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do

have a flag like this

```
boolean quit = false;
```

and a while enclosing your options

```
while(!quit){
...
...
}
```

and

set `quit = true` if the user wants to quit.

**EDIT:**

Something like this

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    System.out.println("Welcome");
    Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        System.out
                .println("Make your choise. \n 1.Check a card number \n 2.Quit.");
        int choise = myinput.nextInt();
        switch (choise) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter your credit card number: ");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Are you sure?");
            String answer = myinput.next();

            if (answer.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Byee :)");
                quit= true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Idiot!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you put that in my program please ?

Comment: @Alper: You may have mistaken StackOverflow for a free work completion service.